# Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I've been stuck on this for a while; this isn't a particularly expensive shader (at least, based on my very limited experience with Metal), yet I still get this message for the first few frames:

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
```

And then I get this one all subsequent frames:

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)
```

This is the vertex shader, which doesn't really do anything:

```
vertex VertexOut viewportProgram(uint vertexID [[ vertex_id ]],
                                 constant float2 *positions [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                 constant float2 *texcoords [[ buffer(1) ]]) {
    VertexOut out;

    out.position.xy = positions[vertexID];
    out.position.z = 0.0; // Only 2D; no depth
    out.position.w = 1.0; // Only 2D; no perspective divide

    out.texcoord = texcoords[vertexID];

    return out;
}
```

Here's my fragment shader, which converts colors from YUV to RGB:

```
fragment float4 colorConvertProgram(VertexOut in [[stage_in]],
                                texture2d<float, access::sample> yTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                                texture2d<float, access::sample> uvTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
                                sampler textureSampler [[ sampler(0) ]]) {


    float3 colorOffset = float3(-(16.0/255.0), -0.5, -0.5);
    float3x3 colorMatrix = float3x3(float3(1.164,  0.000,  1.596),
                                    float3(1.164, -0.392, -0.813),
                                    float3(1.164,  2.017,  0.000));

    float3 yuv = float3(yTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.texcoord).r,
                    uvTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.texcoord).rg);
    float3 rgb = (yuv + colorOffset) * colorMatrix;

    return float4(rgb, 1.0);
}
```

And this is my Swift code that puts it all together:

```
    let samplerDescriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
    samplerDescriptor.minFilter = .linear
    samplerDescriptor.mipFilter = .linear
    samplerDescriptor.sAddressMode = .clampToZero
    samplerDescriptor.tAddressMode = .clampToZero
    let sampler = device.makeSamplerState(descriptor: samplerDescriptor)

    renderEncoder.setViewport(MTLViewport(originX: 0.0, originY: 0.0,
                                          width: Double(bounds.width),
                                          height: Double(bounds.height),
                                          znear: -1.0, zfar: 1.0))
    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexPositionBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexTexcoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(yTexture, index: 0)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(uvTexture, index: 1)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(sampler, index: 0)
    renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)
    renderEncoder.endEncoding()

    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
```

Comment: Are you manually triggering your draw code, or is this being triggered automatically by a metal view delegate?

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but your znear value is invalid. From the [docs for `setViewport()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515527-setviewport): "The values for znear and zfar must be between 0.0 and 1.0, respectively."

Comment: @miweinst I'm triggering it manually

Comment: @KenThomases Didn't know that, thanks! Unfortunately it wasn't the issue though, still have the same error message

Comment: I should say that a GPU hang is always a driver bug. A user-level process should not be able to hang the GPU, no matter what task it submits. So, it makes sense to look for ways to work around it, it's not really your fault. And you should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Ultimately I just decided to use a compute kernel for the color conversion, which works fine. Still have no idea why I got that GPU hang error, though